# Adding previous cell and current cell functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, worksheet-function, excel-indirect

I like to have an Excel Function for:

```
 Previous cell + Current Cell  = Current cell
```

to do this function for the entire row,  when I enter a new value each time, Eg. `A1+A2= A2`.

Comment: That would be a circular reference, which will just result in an error. `A1+A2=A2' will always be 0 because A2 has no designated value (so excel assumes 0), AND the only way a number can equal the sum of something else plus itself is if the other number is 0.

Comment: Thnaks, is there any way to do this by simple funtions. Ex. input 0,1,2,3,4,5 and expected output 1,3,6,10,15

Comment: Well, you could have formulas in the column next to the input. For example, have A1:A6 be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, but the formula in B2 be `=A1+B1` then drag-copy the formula down to B7. Then your values for B2:B7 will be 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15.

Comment: Thanks Bobbitwormjoe, Finally i found it before your answer. The  same way i have done it.  Its working well.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of an answer:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("a1:a"&ROW()))
```

copied down to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Enter Formula =A1+A2 then highlight row and go to Home tab and Fill dropdown then select Right.

More good tips here [Link](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/867-excel-apply-formula-to-entire-column-row.html)

Comment: thanks, But my problem is the excel has add the cell it does for individual cell, Input are 0
1
2
3
4
5 and output are 1
3
6
10
15